# How do I split the mesh using another plane?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I am trying to make a wave with ocean floor. I applied several modifier to generate a wave which is

[image]

I don't want the ocean wave down the plane which need to be removed. At first I tried the Boolean modifier to do a difference but it doesn't make any changes. Is there any split or slice tool available in blender to do the same?

The blend file is available in [image]
[image]

Comment: Boolean should work, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi moonbots. This is just a sample I replicated at home. At my office I have better once which I made using ur tutorial. I will send later. Using boolean I tried but I think due to existing modifiers the waves comes back after difference.

Comment: you can use the bool tool slice operation

Comment: there are inner faces in your ocean objects, as if you had already tried a boolean, the boolean won't work if your topology is not good, do you have a previous version?

Comment: Ok, how do I fix the topology to remove unwanted faces? I have only one version available with me which I attached in the question.

Comment: you need to delete the inner faces, at the end make sure that the normals are ok (alt N > Recalculate Normals). Also it looks like in the N panel > View, your Clip Start is not low enough, it creates invisible faces, decrease it

Comment: The wave in the blend file is having a cut using the boolean modifier. If I give the wave without cut would u help me by suggesting a proper way to cut the wave? I tried to delete the faces but it is still giving waves underneath the cut portion.

Comment: I have a doubt. If I apply a modifier to one side in this case I need to make an ocean wave which only at top. So is it possible to apply modifier on selective faces? If I do that these topological issues won't come I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean didn't work because you have inner faces that make it fail. That said you can limit the *Wave* modifier to the group you want, to do so create a group in *Weight Paint* mode (once done you can soften the weight with the *Blur* brush) or in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups > Assign*. Then choose this group in the *Wave* modifier (and also in the *Displace* modifier if you've used one). Here only the top vertices have been assigned to the group (except the small part that you didn't want) so the bottom won't be affected:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful for me if I want to do the wave change work. But I need to slice the excell bottom part. So I have updated the question again. Please check

Comment: don't you just need to make the bottom flat?

Comment: This method you suggested is for the bottom part?

Comment: it's for the bottom part if you want, please read and try it